# When i use props hideNavBar into Scene component the statusBar collapses and invades the screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

So, i'm using the lib react-native-router-flux to render a webView into my app screen, in this screen there is a image, when i hide the navBar the statusBar goes in front of the image. I dunno what is happening and didnt find any issue to this error:

First Scenario: With NavBar

```
 <Scene
   key="webView"
   component={CustomWebView}
 />
```

[image: first img]

Second Scenario: Without NavBar

```
 <Scene
   key="webView"
   hideNavBar
   component={CustomWebView}
 />
```

[image: second img]

Update: I've found an issue but the answer doesnt work, here is the hyperlink: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1934